# function call in onActivityCreated() triggers Observer every time the app restarts

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-lifecycle, observer-pattern

in my fragment I am observing a live data in a function and in that observer, some sharedPreferences are changed. The function is then called inside onActivityCreated() .The problem is whenever I restart my app the onActivityCreated() gets called which in turn calls that function which in turn observes the live data and thus changes the value of sharedPreference which I don't want.

code to my fragment is attached.

```
package com.example.expensemanager.ui

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.expensemanager.R
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_transaction_list.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.set_balance_details.view.*
import org.eazegraph.lib.models.PieModel


class TransactionListFragment : Fragment() {
    //declaring the view model
    private lateinit var viewModel: TransactionListViewModel
    var cashAmount:Float = 0F
    var bankAmount:Float = 0F
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        //(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(addAppBar)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)
            .get(TransactionListViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transaction_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        //recycler view for showing all the transactions
        with(transaction_list){
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = TransactionAdapter {
                findNavController().navigate(
                    TransactionListFragmentDirections.actionTransactionListFragmentToTransactionDetailFragment(
                        it
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        //code for the floating action button in the main screen
        add_transaction.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController().navigate(
                //here id is passed 0 because the transaction is being added the first time
                TransactionListFragmentDirections.actionTransactionListFragmentToTransactionDetailFragment(
                    0
                )
            )
        }

        addAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            when(menuItem.itemId){
                R.id.calendar_button -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(TransactionListFragmentDirections.actionTransactionListFragmentToCalanderViewFragment())
                    true
                }
                R.id.monthly_cards -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(TransactionListFragmentDirections.actionTransactionListFragmentToMonthlyCardsFragment())
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
        see_all_transactions.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(TransactionListFragmentDirections.actionTransactionListFragmentToAllTransactionsFragment())
        }


        //submitting the new list of upcoming Transactions after getting it from the db
        viewModel.upcomingTransactions.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            (transaction_list.adapter as TransactionAdapter).submitList(it)
        })

        val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("OnboardingDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val monthlyBudget = sharedPreferences.getFloat("monthlyBudget",0F)
        var totalBalance = monthlyBudget*12
        net_balance.text = totalBalance.toString()
        Log.d("netbalance",totalBalance.toString())
        //the net balance (yearly) is calculated wrt the transactions already done
        viewModel.sumOfTransactions.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it != null) {
                totalBalance += it
                net_balance.text = totalBalance.toString()
            }
        })
        val budgetPreferences: SharedPreferences =
                this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("Balance_details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = budgetPreferences.edit()

        //setting pie chart initially to 0
        setPieChart(budgetPreferences,editor)
        //observing the cash details and the bank details to update the text view and the pie chart
        observeBalance(budgetPreferences,editor)
        //GraphCardView code
        //button for setting the balance details
        set_balance_details.setOnClickListener {
            setBalanceDetails(budgetPreferences,editor)
        }
    }
    //dialog box for setting the balance details
    private fun setBalanceDetails(budgetPreferences: SharedPreferences,editor: SharedPreferences.Editor) {
        val dialog = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.set_balance_details,
            null
        )
        //AlertDialogBuilder
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(dialog)
        //show dialog
        val  mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

        dialog.save_details.setOnClickListener {
            cashAmount = dialog.cash_amount.editText?.text.toString().toFloat()
            bankAmount = dialog.bank_amount.editText?.text.toString().toFloat()
            //saving the cashAmount and bankAmount to shared preferences for future use
            editor.putFloat("cashAmount", cashAmount).apply()
            editor.putFloat("bankAmount", bankAmount).apply()

            //setting the pie chart with new values
            setPieChart(budgetPreferences, editor)
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }
        dialog.cancel_details.setOnClickListener { mAlertDialog.dismiss() }
        mAlertDialog.show()
    }

    private fun observeBalance(budgetPreferences: SharedPreferences,editor: SharedPreferences.Editor) {
        //getting the cashAmount and bankAmount and updating the views with live data

        var cashAmount = budgetPreferences.getFloat("cashAmount", 0F)
        var bankAmount = budgetPreferences.getFloat("bankAmount", 0F)
        viewModel.cashAmount.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            if (it != null) {
                cashAmount += it
                cash.text = "CASH : ${cashAmount}"
                Log.d("observeCash",cashAmount.toString())
                editor.putFloat("cashAmount",cashAmount).apply()//find solution to this
                setPieChart(budgetPreferences,editor)
            }
        })

        viewModel.bankAmount.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it != null) {
                bankAmount+=it
                bank.text = "BANK : ${bankAmount}"
                Log.d("observeBank",bankAmount.toString())
                editor.putFloat("cashAmount",cashAmount).apply()
                setPieChart(budgetPreferences,editor)
            }
        })
        setPieChart(budgetPreferences,editor)
    }
    //https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-pie-chart-into-an-android-application/ use this for reference
    private fun setPieChart(budgetPreferences: SharedPreferences,editor: SharedPreferences.Editor) {

        val cashAmount = budgetPreferences.getFloat("cashAmount", 0f)
        val bankAmount = budgetPreferences.getFloat("bankAmount", 0f)
        Log.d("pieCank",cashAmount.toString())
        Log.d("pieBank",bankAmount.toString())
        cash.text = "CASH : ${cashAmount}"
        bank.text = "BANK : ${bankAmount}"

        val pieEntries = arrayListOf<PieEntry>()
        pieEntries.add(PieEntry(cashAmount))
        pieEntries.add(PieEntry(bankAmount))
        pieChart.animateXY(1000, 1000)

        // setup PieChart Entries Colors
        val pieDataSet = PieDataSet(pieEntries, "This is Pie Chart Label")
        pieDataSet.setColors(
            ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.blue1),
            ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.blue2)
        )
        val pieData = PieData(pieDataSet)

        // setip text in pieChart centre
        //piechart.setHoleColor(R.color.teal_700)
        pieChart.setHoleColor(getColorWithAlpha(Color.BLACK, 0.0f))
        // hide the piechart entries tags
        pieChart.legend.isEnabled = false
//        now hide the description of piechart
        pieChart.description.isEnabled = false
        pieChart.description.text = "Expanses"
        pieChart.holeRadius = 40f
        // this enabled the values on each pieEntry
        pieData.setDrawValues(true)
        pieChart.data = pieData

    }
    fun getColorWithAlpha(color: Int, ratio: Float): Int {
        var newColor = 0
        val alpha = Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * ratio)
        val r = Color.red(color)
        val g = Color.green(color)
        val b = Color.blue(color)
        newColor = Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b)
        return newColor
    }
}
```

As seen when app restarts , viewModel.cashAmount gets triggered giving undesired outputs.
What can i do to avoid this .

Answer (score 0):

Activities can get recreated a lot, like when you rotate the screen, or if it's in the background and the system destroys it to free up some memory. Right now, every time that happens your code doesn't know whether it's getting the current value, or a brand new one, but one of those should perform a calculation, and the other should just update the display.

The problem is your calculation logic is tied in with the UI state - it's being told what to display, and also deciding if that counts as a new user action or not. And it has no way of knowing that. Your logic needs to go something like

```
things observe LiveData values -> update to display new values when they come in
user clicks a button -> do calculation with the value they've entered
calculation result returns -> LiveData gets updated with new value
LiveData value changes -> things update to show the new value
```

that way a calculation happens *specifically* in response to a user action, like through a button click. `LiveData` observers only reflect the current state, so it doesn't matter if they see the same value lots of times, they're just redrawing a pie chart or whatever.

---

You can use a `LiveData` to watch for a stream of values, but the thing about UI components is that sometimes they're there to see them, and sometimes they're not. And `LiveData` is specifically made to push updates to active observers, but not inactive ones - and always provide the most recent value to a new observer, or one that becomes active.

So in that case it works more like "here's the current situation", and that fits better with displaying things, where it doesn't matter if you repeat yourself. That's why you can't do this kind of "handle everything exactly one time" thing in your UI - unless you're literally responding to a UI event like a button click